# Improvement on hash function

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, hash, vector, spatial

It's about spatial hashing for 2d... (Excuse me if it's not spatial hashing I'm talking about)
We translate x and y coord to an index in array representing buckets (groups).
All papers/articles I've read, and myself use:
`int grid_cell = x/cell_size + y/cell_size*width;`
**In AS3, would it be more efficient** to precalculate the indices for every x and y and storing the results in 2 vectors such as *xMap:Vector.<int> contains x/cell_size and yMap:Vector.<int> y/cell_size*width* then retrieve it using:
`int grid_cell = xMap[x] + yMap[y]; // grid being the array of buckets`

**In short:** is retrieving an item from a vector faster than a calculation such as *y/cell_size*width* in AS3 ??
My own bench-marking's results fluctuate a lot for me to decide and this is a performance critical function.

Comment: First of all - welcome to stackoverflow and what a nice first post. Second of all, you say that your own benchmarking results fluctuate a lot? Have you tried running ONLY the function to calculate this, and then running it eg. 1000 times compared to 1000 times using the other method to check? I'd believe that the array method would always be faster, however, it'd take up more memory, but I haven't done the benchmarks.

Comment: Probably depends on the length of the vector

Comment: Are all your coordinates integers? Or do you need to hash intermediate values as well?

Comment: @ jmh_gr: they are all integers of course, no array would hold all numbers even from 0 to 0.1 *** @h2ooooooo: thx for a heart warming welcome :) I redid my test in a release version (thx for jackson dunstan's website for this clarification). It turns out the vector method is at least 1.5x faster than calculation for up to a vector length of 3000 (@ The_asMan) which is more than i need.

Comment: @Chadyk Glad you figured it out - remember to answer and accept your own question so others can find your solution as well (I *think* you can with 11 reputation, but I'm not sure - neither the less I think it takes a bit of time before you can do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the Vector is really, really massive it will be quicker to look up values than calculate them.